# Permissions required to rum make install and yum update

Tags: linux, yum, openssl

I am researching on Openssl update manually and openssl update through yum update.

I have figured out the commands to do it.

But searching on permissions required to make install and yum update.

Could some one tell me permissions for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions you need are root permissions. Run `sudo` in front of your commands!